# PHP: The value of boolean in if statement

Tags: php, forms

```
if ($_POST) {
    $family = array("Rob", "Kirsten", "Tommy", "Ralphie");
    $isKnown = false;
    foreach ($family as $value) {
        if ($value == $_POST['name']) {
            $isKnown = true;
        }  
    }
    if ($isKnown) {
        echo "Hi there ".$_POST['name']."!";
    } else {
        echo "I don't know you.";
    }      
}

<form method="post">
    <p>What is your name?</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="name"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Now `isKnown = false` but in the last if statement

```
if ($isKnown) {
     echo "Hi there ".$_POST['name']."!";
} else {
     echo "I don't know you.";
}
```

I can't understand it... Now `$isKnown = false` and it says when `$isknown` is `false` say the code that would saying when `isknown` is `true`...

I understand all code but the only thing I can't is in last `if` what is the value of `$isKnown` and how it got this value.

What the value of `$isknown` in this if statement: `true` or `false`?

Comment: What is your test value of `$_POST`?

Comment: What do you want 2 know?

Comment: if ($isKnown) {

        echo "Hi there ".$_POST['name']."!";

    } else {

        echo "I don't know you.";

    }      
What the value of $isknow in this if sta. true or false ?

Comment: My Test value is omar

Comment: Is the code above your whole code?

Comment: And try to use `var_dump($family)` and show us the output.

Comment: If that is your output, did you forget the `<?` and `?>`?

Comment: the only thing i want to know is in last If statement if($isKnown) Now $isKnow is true or false ?! :)

Comment: No i didn't forget it :)

Comment: Please  use var_dump($family) and show us the output, because your code should result in `false` instead of `true`

Comment: its not my code but i can't understand who it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works in the following way.If you have submitted the form,then only the value $isknown is set.If it is set, the default value of $isknown is false.

If $_POST['name'] is present in $family, then $isknown is set to true.

Now incase of if($isknown), if $isknown is true,it will echo hi there $_POST['name'] and if $unknown is false, it will echo i dont know u

Comment: yeah nice, But the last question is in last if statement if $_POST['name'] is one of family now the value of $unknown is true and if it is not one of the family it should be false and the last statement in code if($isknown) thats means if the default value of isKnow is its deafult value so do some code , right ?

Comment: Yeah Thank you but can you tell me why incase of if($isKnown) the default value of it is true that when we say if($isknown) if $isknown is true,it will echo hi there $_POST['name']? and thank you for your perfect explain

Comment: my question is another way why the value of $isKnown incase of if  is true not false like in the 3rd line in PHP

Comment: The if statement works in the following way :  if(true), it executes the statement in the if loop, if(false), it executes the statement in the else loop where  false and true are boolean values

Comment: that is because we are overwriting it as true  if $_POST['name'] is present in $family

Answer (score 0):

So, the following is the flow of what you wanted to do:

First, we receive value(s) of `$_POST['name']` via a form post and we set the value of variable `$isKnown` to `false`.

Then we will the value of `$_POST['name']` in the  given array `$family`.

If `$_POST['name']` matches one of the values in `$family` array then we will set the value of `$isKnown` to true and in the end we will be getting the message on the boolean value of `$isKnown`.

Actually there is a shorter way to that:

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
 $family = array("Rob", "Kirsten", "Tommy", "Ralphie");


         if(in_array($_POST['name'], $family)){
            echo "Hi there ".$_POST['name']."!";
          }else{
            echo "I don't know you.";
          }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... But can you tell me why in my case in last if statement when we say if ($isKnown) {
>             
>             echo "Hi there ".$_POST['name']."!";
>             
>         } else {
>             
>             echo "I don't know you.";
>             
>         }``
$isKnown is true Not false like we set it in the first line ? :)

Comment: Because in the first if statement (inside foreach loop) if $_POST['name'] found in the $family array you are changing it's value to true. So in the second statement you are getting this true.